# Looping a rolling window for use in package functions

Tags: r, loops, rolling-computation

I am working on market efficiency tests for a research project, where I am using dynamic hurst exponentials and Lo & MacKinlay variance ratio tests. To do this, I was planning on using the pracma and vrtest packages. The problem occurs when I am running the tests, because they are not inherently dynamic, meaning that to get a time-varying measure I will essentially need to run the following codes:

```
hurstexp(data$GB[2:101])$Hs
hurstexp(data$GB[3:102])$Hs
hurstexp(data$GB[4:103])$Hs
```

```
Lo.Mac(data$GB[2:101] , c(2, 4, 8, 16))
Lo.Mac(data$GB[3:102] , c(2, 4, 8, 16))
Lo.Mac(data$GB[4:103] , c(2, 4, 8, 16))
```

Since I am working on a data set with over 3000 observations it would be useful if this could be automated.

My thought was that I could create a variable which loops the interval of 100 sample values through the entire population, i.e. a rolling window variable. If everything works, then I would be able to insert the rolling window variable in to the package functions and get the 100 day hurst exponent/VR(k) for each overlapping increment. This is the loop and the results I arrived at:

```
lv = for (i in 1:(length(data$GB)-interval)) {
  j = i + interval
  data$GB[i:j]
}
lv

library(pracma)
hurstexp(lv)$Hs

library(vrtest)
Lo.Mac(lv , c(2, 4, 8, 16))
```

**Errors/output:**
NULL
Error in hurstexp(lv) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),:'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

The data variable data$GB consists of log returns. To reproduce the data the following code can be used:

```
reproduce = rnorm(3000, mean = -0.0004832595, sd = 0.003566892)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some examples.  The third argument to `rollapplyr` can be any function of the input window that returns a scalar or vector.

```
library(zoo)
x <- 1:10 # test data

rollapplyr(x, 3, sum, fill = NA)
##  [1] NA NA  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27

rollapplyr(x, 3, c, fill = NA)
##       [,1] [,2] [,3]
##  [1,]   NA   NA   NA
##  [2,]   NA   NA   NA
##  [3,]    1    2    3
##  [4,]    2    3    4
##  [5,]    3    4    5
##  [6,]    4    5    6
##  [7,]    5    6    7
##  [8,]    6    7    8
##  [9,]    7    8    9
## [10,]    8    9   10

rollapplyr(x, 3, toString, fill = NA)
##  [1] NA         NA         "1, 2, 3"  "2, 3, 4"  "3, 4, 5"  "4, 5, 6" 
##  [7] "5, 6, 7"  "6, 7, 8"  "7, 8, 9"  "8, 9, 10"

library(vrtest)
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(10, mean = -0.0004832595, sd = 0.003566892)
rollapplyr(y, 7, function(y) Lo.Mac(y = y, kvec = c(2, 4))$Stats)
##              M11        M12        M21        M22
## [1,] -0.73484310 -1.0934219 -1.0728625 -1.5237487
## [2,] -1.14450313 -1.1145049 -3.1935343 -1.8419056
## [3,] -0.09729379 -1.0237798 -0.1648527 -1.4823474
## [4,]  0.73536076 -0.7280281  1.1079997 -0.9003987
```

Comment: This worked exactly like I had hoped. Thank you very much!